# Handle ZIP files with Groovy Script

Tags: groovy, groovyshell

I need help with how to use Groovy Script to:

1. Extract files from a ZIP file
2. Zip files

Comment: Can you show us what you tried?

Comment: I have tried below source code. But it's not working

Comment: import org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils
import java.nio.file.Files
import java.nio.file.Paths
import java.util.zip.ZipFile

def unzipFile(File file) {
    cleanupFolder()
    def zipFile = new ZipFile(file)
    zipFile.entries().each { it ->
        def path = Paths.get('c:\\folder\\' + it.name)
        if(it.directory){
            Files.createDirectories(path)}
        else {
            def parentDir = path.getParent()
            if (!Files.exists(parentDir)) {
                Files.createDirectories(parentDir)
            }Files.copy(zipFile.getInputStream(it), path)} } }

Comment: private cleanupFolder() {
    FileUtils.deleteDirectory(new File('c:\\folder\\'))
}

Comment: I have googled some source code and tried.

Comment: @user7439525 put the code you added to comments in the question then click the {} icon above text area to format

Answer (score 0):

if you have all groovy libraries in classpath, then you can use `AntBuilder`

```
new AntBuilder().unzip( src: "/path_to/archive.zip", dest: "/path_where_to_extract" )
```

here `unzip` - groovy styled Apache Ant command

and to see more examples : https://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/unzip.html